# TSP matrix why is my result always 0?

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, traveling-salesman

I'm working on my traveling sales program(without the use of the STL)

I know this shouldn't be giving me the correct answer. I'm trying to make sure my matrix is being loaded correctly first.

Can anyone see the problem here? I always get 0 for the total cost no matter what I put in.

On a side note: how do I read more than one character from a line. I actually need the characters starting at spot 6.

```
//method for getting the minimum cost of the given routes.

void getCost(){

for(int i = 0; i <50; i++){


for(int j = 0; j <50; j++){

    if (graph[i][j]>0)
        totalCost == totalCost + graph[i][j];


   }

}

}

   switch (line[0]) {

      case 'c':


        cCount++;

        cout << "Added City: " << line << "\n";

         break;

      case 'a':

         aCount++;

         c1 = line[2];
         c2 = line[4];
         cost = line[6];
         cout << "Added Route: " << line << "\n";
         graph[c1][c2] == cost;



         break;

      default:

        getCost();
        cout << totalCost;

         stop = true;
         break;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is a comparison, not an assignment; it does not change `totalCost`:

```
totalCost == totalCost + graph[i][j];
```

To fix this, write

```
totalCost = totalCost + graph[i][j];
```

or, equivalently but more concisely

```
totalCost += graph[i][j];
```

Comment: I did that, but it still returns 0. Apparently there is more than one problem

Comment: @ClaytonBrant: Have you fixed the identical problem in `graph[c1][c2] == cost`?

Comment: Yes I did, I even checked to make sure that line 2 4 and 6 had elements.